# Mongoose update's pre crashes with 3rd parameter "UPSERT : TRUE"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I execute the method `myUpdate` mongoose throws the error :

"TypeError: object is not a function at Query.update.callback"

Why occurs because I pass the third parameter with the `upsert : true` object rather than the callback..any idea how to fix this?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    function myUpdate(pUser) {

     var user = new User(pUser);
    user.update({ "username": user.username }, user, { upsert: true }, function (err) {
         //dostuff
        })
    }

    userSchema.pre('update', function (next) {
       var user = this;
        if (user.email) { 

        }
        else {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
var user = new User(pUser);
user.update({ "username": user.username }, user, { upsert: true },          function (err) {
    //dostuff
})
```

use this

```
var user = new User(pUser);
User.update({ "username": user.username }, user, { upsert: true },          function (err) {
    //dostuff
})
```

User.update